# Get Payment Status after payment through Paypal

Tags: laravel, paypal

I am using srmklive/paypal ~1.0 PHP package for papayl integration.

I want to update my order Payment status after payment if Paymetn Success status should be 1 else it would be 0

```
  $request->validate([
            'fname' => 'required',
            'lname' => 'required',
            'country' => 'required',
            'city' => 'required',
            'state' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required',
            'zip' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
        ]);
        $order = new Order();
        $order->fname = $request->fname;
        $order->lname = $request->lname;
        $order->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $order->email = $request->email;
        $order->phone = $request->phone;
        $order->country = $request->country;
        $order->city = $request->city;
        $order->state = $request->state;
        $order->street_address = $request->address;
        $order->zip = $request->zip;
        $order->total_price = $request->total_price;
        $order->notes = $request->notes;
        $order->status = 0;
        $order->tracking_no = 'Insha'.rand(1111,9999);
        $order->save();


     
        $data = [];
        $data['items'] = [];
        $data['invoice_description'] = $request->notes;
        $data['invoice_id'] = 1;

        $data['return_url'] = route('order.payment.success');
        $data['cancel_url'] = route('order.payment.cancel');
        $data['total'] = $request->total_price;


        $provider = new ExpressCheckout();
        $response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data);
        $response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data, true);


        return redirect($response['paypal_link']);
```

Payment Success Method is

```
    public function payment_success(){
        Alert::success('Success', "Order Placed Successfully");
        return redirect()->route('fronthome');
    }
```

How can i update $oder->status wtih payment status

Answer (score 0):

I Got the answer

I just update my payment_success method with

```
public function payment_success(Request $request)
    {
        // Retrieve the payment status and other relevant data from the PayPal response
        $token = $request->get('token');
        $payerId = $request->get('PayerID');

        // Create an instance of the PayPal ExpressCheckout service
        $provider = new ExpressCheckout();

        // Get the details of the payment using the token
        $paymentDetails = $provider->getExpressCheckoutDetails($token);

        // Check if the payment was successful
        if ($paymentDetails['ACK'] === 'Success') {
            // Update the order status to indicate successful payment
            $orderId = $paymentDetails['INVNUM']; // Assuming you have an invoice number stored in INVNUM

             $order = Order::where('id', $orderId)->first();
            if ($order) {
                $order->status = 1; // Set the status to 1 for successful payment
                $order->update();
            }

            Alert::success('Success', "Order Placed Successfully");
            return redirect()->route('fronthome');
        } else {
            // Handle the case when payment was not successful
            // You can redirect to an error page or take appropriate actions
            Alert::error('Error', "Payment Failed");
            return redirect()->route('order.payment.cancel');
        }
    }
```